# Resolve peer dependency of aliased package breaks npm install

Tags: npm, package.json

I'm trying to test my npm package against different versions of React. So I set up aliases for older version in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-plugin-i18n-l10n",
  [..]
  "peerDependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^4.x",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.x",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.x",
    "react-intl": "^5.20.x"
  },
  "peerDependenciesMeta": {
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": {
      "optional": true
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    [..]
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-17": "npm:react@17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom-17": "npm:react-dom@17.0.2",
    [..]
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer-17": "npm:react-test-renderer@17.0.2",
    [..]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "limax": "^3.0.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

While researching this I've found another question which is similar [NPM: Link peer dependency to package alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70837112/npm-link-peer-dependency-to-package-alias), which works, but `npm install` still throws the following error:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: gatsby-plugin-i18n-l10n@4.6.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   dev react@"18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.2" from react-dom-17@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom-17
npm ERR!   dev react-dom-17@"npm:react-dom@17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

How can I make `npm install` work again and help it to resolve the packages by itself?

Answer (score 0):

*I rewrote my comment as I did not get the problem at first

It is possible, but you will need to manually edit the package-lock file of NPM.

In steps as follows:

1. Leave only the legacy dependencies in the package.json file like so:

```
    {
      "name": "npmpeerstest",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "type": "module",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@legacy/react": "npm:react@^17.0.2",
        "@legacy/react-dom": "npm:react-dom@^17.0.2"
      }
    }
```

2. Run npm install, it should pass ok
3. Edit package-lock.json from this:

```
"node_modules/@legacy/react-dom": {
      "name": "react-dom",
      "version": "17.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom/-/react-dom-17.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-s4h96KtLDUQlsENhMn1ar8t2bEa+q/YAtj8pPPdIjPDGBDIVNsrD9aXNWqspUe6AzKCIG0C1HZZLqLV7qpOBGA==",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
        "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
        "scheduler": "^0.20.2"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "17.0.2"
      }
    },
```

to:

```
"node_modules/@legacy/react-dom": {
      "name": "react-dom",
      "version": "17.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom/-/react-dom-17.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-s4h96KtLDUQlsENhMn1ar8t2bEa+q/YAtj8pPPdIjPDGBDIVNsrD9aXNWqspUe6AzKCIG0C1HZZLqLV7qpOBGA==",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
        "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
        "scheduler": "^0.20.2"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@legacy/react": "17.0.2"
      }
    },
```

Notice that we need to manually set the react dependency to use the @legacy/react instead of react

4. Add new dependencies to package.json like so:

```
{
  "name": "npmpeerstest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@legacy/react": "npm:react@^17.0.2",
    "@legacy/react-dom": "npm:react-dom@^17.0.2",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0"
  }
}
```

5. Run npm install, and all should pass

*do not forget to commit the package-lock.json with the modification or other installs will fail

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It should work, but I should not edit `package-lock.json` by hand.

Comment: Well, then I see one option: to republish react in a private npm registry (or just a private package in npm) with a prefux, and then republish react-dom with a modified dependency to your republished react instead of the real react again with a prefix.